# Why is my math not working on my SQL Server database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database

I am developing an asp.net web application and I am trying to add a user xp system to it. I have a SQL Server database connected to it and I am trying to make a function that will give 5 experience points to the user.

I queried to the user that is logged in, accessed the `user_xp` column, and I am trying to add +5 to the old session variable for xp, then send that back into the database to be stored. Here is my code, I am not sure what is wrong with it.

```
void generateXp()
{
        try
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);

            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                con.Open();
            }

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE member_master_tbl SET user_xp = @user_xp WHERE " +
                "user_name = '" + Session["username"].ToString().Trim() + "'", con);
            int xp = 5;
            int current_xp = Convert.ToInt32(Session["user_xp"]);
            int new_xp = xp + current_xp;
            string new_xp2 = Convert.ToString(new_xp);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("user_xp", new_xp2);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks! NEVER construct SQL statements from user input. Use Query Parameters instead,

Comment: Why are you using a parameter for the `SET` part of your `UPDATE` - and then switching back to the old, crappy string concatenation for the `WHERE` part?? Use **parameters ALL the time!**

Comment: After you fix your parameter problem, you do need to Execute the query at some point.

Comment: why do you store a number as a string?

Comment: And don't use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/). Laziness is a bad habit and difficult to un-learn.

Comment: You don't ever execute the command...?

Comment: @KlausGütter is there anywhere specific i can learn about Query Parameters?

Comment: @SMor what should i do instead?

Comment: You should be disposing your connection and command (and reader if any) objects with `using` blocks, you don't need to check if a newly created connection is closed, it always is. And don't swallow exceptions

Comment: *is there anywhere specific i can learn about Query Parameters?* well, you're already using one here: `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("user_xp", new_xp2);`

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming the SQL parameter to @user_xp.

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user_xp", new_xp2);
```

I don't have an accessible database to test. Also, you need to add the command to execute the query at the end.
`cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`
That being said, it's a good practice to learn to separate DB queries to stored procedures or functions.

Answer (score 0):

As others noted, you simply forgot to do a execute non query to run the command that you setup.

However, you can write things this way. You don't mention or note what the data type the experience points column is - I assumed "int".

So, your code block can be written this way:

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE member_master_tbl SET user_xp = @user_xp WHERE user_name = @user",
      new SqlConnection(strcon)))
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@user_xp", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 5 + Session("user_xp");
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@user", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Session("username");

    cmd.Connection.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

note how the command object has a connection object (so we don't need a separate one).

And while several people here "lamented" the string concentration to build the sql and warned about sql injection?

Actually, the introduction of @ parameters for both values cleans up the code. So you get nice parameters - nice type checking, and you don't have to remember to add/use/have things like quotes around teh string, but not for numbers.

And I let .net cast the number expression from session() - this also likely is ok.

Also the "using block" also correctly cleans up the command object and also the connection object - so the using block is a good idea here.